# I try cd code in Ubuntu16.04, but the screen shows Input/output error'

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-16.04, cd

My machine suddenly shutdown because of no power. After that, I reboot the machine, and I try the command `"cd ./code"`, but **there is an error**

> "bash: cd: code: Input/output error".

I try to uninstall **tensorflow**, but there is **another error**

> "IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error"

I think that the filesystem may be damaged, but there are no problems in some files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to reinstall your system because of corrupted system files which are in control of peripheral devices like Hard Drive, DVD and all ports that are in the back of your PC.

These devices are all peripheral, the south bridge on the motherboard controls them.

Comment: Only part of the files or directories are corrupted? Some files are ok, and i can operate these files.

Comment: Yes, there are a few corrupted files maybe or the hard drive is failing.

Type dmesg and check the last few lines of output. If the disc or the connection to it is failing, it'll be noted there.